# Running a ASP 3.0 site _in_ a ASP.NET runtime

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, mono

Is it possible to get ASP 3.0 pages to run under a .NET runtime?

My basis for asking is that I was pondering the posibillity to run an old site under linux and mono. And this site is pure asp/vbscript. (There are a few COM+ usage points, but those are easy to refactor out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [ASP Classic compiler](http://aspclassiccompiler.codeplex.com/) (Open Source)

Comment: I just tried it and this solution worked well for me. I'm also going to try get it working on mono but I'm sure that's going to be a tad more difficult.

Comment: @Christian Wattengård Status update: the ASP compiler does not work well for ASP 3.0. It doesn't support classes, server.execute, eval, or any other more recent ASP features. That makes this pretty much a non-starter for my project. However, I was able to get it running on Ubuntu Natty with mono and aside from those grievances it worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for the update @MikeMurko. I'll give the answer anyway, since it's actually a good recommendation. Even if your mileage may vary :)